# Backbone save model issues

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to save a model and on success, unrender it:
problem is that from within success i can't reference the this reference (which is the view) and I also cannot reference the variable isOk.status that this.model.save(...) returns.
the code:

```
save: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var isOk = this.model.save(null,
        {
            wait: true,

            success: function(model, response){
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.status);

            },

            error: function(model, response){
                console.log("error");
                console.log($.parseJSON(response.responseText));
                $('#errorMessage').empty();
                $('#errorMessage').append($.parseJSON(response.responseText).error);
                $('#errorApproveModal').modal({
                    keyboard: true
                });
            }
        });
    console.log('logging isOk');
    console.log(isOk);
    //this one is working! It's on validate event
    if(!isOk){
        $('#errorMessage').empty();
        $('#errorMessage').append("Error: there was an error");
        $('#errorApproveModal').modal({
            keyboard: true
        });

        return false

    }
    console.log(isOk);
    **//both those checks are not working for some reason.**
    //
    if(isOk.status == 200 || isOk.statusText == "OK"){
        console.log('in is ok');
        this.remove();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Btw the view is:

```
App.Views.User = Backbone.View.extend({
      model: App.Models.User
      ,
      save: function...
});
```

Can someone please help?
Is there a better way to handle the success and error than this method?
Thanks!!
Roy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it but I always just declare a variable referencing `this` from the view's function, then use that in success. Something like this:

```
save: function(e) {

    // ADD THIS LINE
    var me = this;

    var isOk = this.model.save(null,
        {

    ....
            success: function(model, response){
                // USE me IN HERE
                me.render(); // e.g

            },
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can do this:

save: function(e) {

```
var isOk = this.model.save(null,
    {

....
        success: function(model, response,options){
            // USE me IN HERE
            this.options.me.render(); // e.g

        },
        //ADD me this 
        me : this
....
}
```

With the options,you can do all your parameters.